# MySQL output by columns

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have database for football (soccer) statisitics. I want to show first three teams through seasons in this fashion http://footballfacts.ru/turnircats/105166-chempionat-sssr

I have table for stats through seasons that contains this columns (and some other, not interesting in this case) called clubseason:

- idClubSeason
- idClub
- idSeason
- clubPosition

Next tables that I have are for clubs and seasons, each containg ids (idClub and idSeason) and names (name of club and season). So three tables in relational database. Is there help to output SQL query in php in that manner?

My query is like this:

```
    SELECT `jos_igraciDB_club`.`name` , `jos_igraciDB_season`.`idSeason`, `jos_igraciDB_season`.`name`,`jos_clubseason`.`clubPosition`, `jos_igraciDB_club`.`idClub`
FROM `jos_clubseason` 
LEFT JOIN `jos_igraciDB_club` ON `jos_clubseason`.`idClub` = `jos_igraciDB_club`.`idClub` 
LEFT JOIN `jos_igraciDB_season` ON `jos_clubseason`.`idSeason` = `jos_igraciDB_season`.`idSeason` 
ORDER BY `jos_clubseason`.`clubPosition` ASC
```

Comment: **Moderator note**: Please keep comments civil and constructive. Thank you.

Comment: sqlfiddle with data. Show a sample usage, and expected results in tabular fashion.

Comment: My results are like this  [link]http://i.imgur.com/GEdawQE.jpg

Comment: I want to be in this format by columns
season.name | 1st club name | 2nd club name | 3rd club name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1922/1923 | Građanski (Zagreb) | SAŠK (Sarajevo) | Jugoslavija (Beograd) 
1923/1924 | Jugoslavija (Beograd) | Hajduk (Split) | SAŠK (Sarajevo)
etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exact database structure that you have, so you'll have to join additional tables for names etc, but this should be enough to get you an idea how to solve it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d22e29/6

```
SELECT
  cs.season,
  first.club,
  second.club,
  third.club
FROM
  clubseason cs
  INNER JOIN clubseason first  ON first.season  = cs.season AND first.position  = 1 
  INNER JOIN clubseason second ON second.season = cs.season AND second.position = 2 
  INNER JOIN clubseason third  ON third.season  = cs.season AND third.position  = 3 
GROUP BY cs.season
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer I looking for. It is pretty simple as I see now. That is when your brain dont react as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  jos_igraciDB_season.name,
  cnf.name, cns.name, cnt.name,
  cs.idSeason,
  first.idClub,
  second.idClub,
  third.idClub
FROM
  jos_clubseason cs
  INNER JOIN jos_clubseason first  ON first.idSeason  = cs.idSeason AND first.clubPosition  = 1
  INNER JOIN jos_clubseason second ON second.idSeason = cs.idSeason AND second.clubPosition = 2
  INNER JOIN jos_clubseason third  ON third.idSeason  = cs.idSeason AND third.clubPosition  = 3
  LEFT JOIN jos_igraciDB_club cnf ON first.idClub = cnf.idClub AND first.clubPosition  = 1
  LEFT JOIN jos_igraciDB_club cns ON second.idClub = cns.idClub AND second.clubPosition  = 2
  LEFT JOIN jos_igraciDB_club cnt ON third.idClub = cnt.idClub AND third.clubPosition  = 3
  LEFT JOIN jos_igraciDB_season ON cs.idSeason = jos_igraciDB_season.idSeason
GROUP BY cs.idSeason
```